# GetListItem - Get Distinct Values for Dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-services, client-object-model, jquery

I am Passing the XML for getting List item and binding to dropdown. Here i have shown the code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <title></title>
     <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<select id="input2" style="width:30%"><option>Any</option></select>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var soapEnv =
  "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
  <soapenv:Body> \
  <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
  <listName>as</listName> \
  <viewFields> \
  <ViewFields> \
  <FieldRef Name='Team_x0020_name'/> \
  </ViewFields> \
  </viewFields> \
  </GetListItems> \
  </soapenv:Body> \
  </soapenv:Envelope>";
             $.ajax({
                 url: "../_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "xml",
                 data: soapEnv,
                 complete: processResult,
                 contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
             });
         });


       var select = $('#input2');

         function processResult(xData, status) {
             $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
                 select.append("<option>" + $(this).attr("ows_Team_x0020_name") + "</option>");     

            });
 }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get the distinct Values from the listitem. Is it Possible or not from the above code?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done things like this is int past is to throw all the values into an array, sort it, remove the duplicates, then append it. So something like (untested):

```
     function processResult(xData, status) {
       var optionValues = [];
       $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z\\:row").each(function () {
          optionValues.push($(this).attr("ows_Team_x0020_name"));
       });
      var sorted = optionvalues.sort();
      var results = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (sorted[i + 1] == sorted[i]) {
            results.push(sorted[i]);
        }
       }
      sorted.each(function(idx, val){
      select.append("<option>" + val + "</option>");
    });
}
```